# Find the Direction(s) of the Line segment that gives you the maximum, minimum and a value of 0 for the line intergral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I have a question as Follows:

Let F(x,y) = ( (x^2 + y^2),(x^2 + y^2) ), and let C be the straight line segment of length 1, with an end point at the origin. Find the direction of C such that the line integral $$\int \vec F \cdot d\vec R\ $$ is **a maximum, a minimum and zero.** Give the direction of C and the value of the integral.

I have been stuck for hours on this ! My first would be to just use general values for (x,y), plug it into the $$ \vec r(t) = (1-t)(0,0) + t(x,y) = (xt,yt)    $$ $$ d\vec r = (x,y)$$ and let $$ \vec F = (x^2 + y^2) dx + (x^2 + y^2) dy $$

and just go from there. However my mind just goes blank at this stage and I don't know if I'm on the right path...

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the advice and help everyone. I didn't find an answer by continuing along the same path as mentioned above. Still got stuck.... What  I did was to find the gradient vector and that would be the greatest direction of change. then following the definition $$ \int \vec F \cdot T ds $$

T in my case would be the curve C  which has length 1.By using the identity that $$ [ \vec F \cdot T ] =||F||||T||Cos(\theta ) $$ $$[ \vec F \cdot T ] =||F||(1)Cos(\theta ) $$ and length vector F is $$ || \vec F || =  \sqrt{ (x^2+y^2)^2 + (x^2+y^2)^2} = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{2} $$ Now we got $$ \sqrt{2}Cos(\theta) $$  and from here it would be easy to get the max, min and value of zero for the line integral.

Any ideas on using this approach?

Comment: You are on the right path. Hint: use $(x_0,y_0)$ instead of $(x,y)$ for the coordinates oof the end point of $C$. This will save you some confusion.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - Thanks for the tip. I was still unable to find an answer using that approach... I decided to Maximize the Dot Product.

Comment: My tip, by the way, is exactly the same as DonAntonio's one. The path you have taken now seems wrong to me, I suspect you are confusing $(x, y)$ with $(x_0, y_0)$ (called $(a,b)$ in DonAntonio's answer).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the good work you began with, but changing to $\;(a,b)\;$ instead of $\;(x,y)\;$... and **remember**: $a^2+b^2=1\;$ (why?) :

$$\int_C\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_0^1(a^2t^2+b^2t^2,\,a^2t^2+b^2t^2)\cdot(a,b)dt=\int_0^1\left(a^3+ab^2+a^2b+b^3\right)t^2\,dt=$$

$$\frac13\left(a^3+ab^2+a^2b+b^3\right)=\frac13\left(a(a^2+b^2)+b(a^2+b^2)\right)=\frac13(a+b)$$

Well, now you have the easy task to find out where the above is zero, maximal and minimal, when $\;(a,b)\;$ belongs to the unit circle...

Comment: Appreciate the help! Yes, using either this approach of GiuseppeNegro's approach was very useful.

Comment: But I do also believe that here we have shown two ways of potentially solving this issue,  your way and the one I found...